# How to make an html section right justified and shift to a new row if the window is narrow?

Tags: html, css

I want to have some text on my html page appear near the right side, so I used a table to arrange the information in cells and right justified the rightmost one using css like this:

```
table { display: block; }
td { display: inline-block; }
```

That looks proper when there is enough width on the window to display it all.  However if the window is narrow (like on a phone or just resizing the browser to be narrow), the two cells merge in an ugly way.

I'd like the right cell to shift to a new row if there isn't room for both.  I found how to do that also, but only if I don't right-justify the cell using css like this:

```
.righty {
  position: absolute; 
  right: 20px; 
}
```

How can I do both?  I've written a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5bw5fjc/) to demonstrate both cases above, plus my attempt to do both but the combined attempt does not work.

What I want to end up with is the best of both worlds. The text in the right showing near the right side of the page until the width won't allow it, otherwise have it shift under the first cell.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to experiment with flex-box, here is an example. Note the @media query is what allows you to change the layout when the browser window becomes narrow.

```
<style>  
    section {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }

    .shifty {
        border: 1px solid blue;
        margin: 5px;
        font-size: 150%;
    }

    @media (max-width: 600px) {
        section {flex-flow: column; }
    }   
</style>

<section>
    <div class="shifty">
        Here is the left side<br>
        With a couple<br>
        of lines in it.
    </div>
    <div class="shifty">
        Here is the right side and<br>
        if the window is narrow<br>
        it will shift under the first <br>
        cell nicely instead of overlapping.
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tables cannot "wrap" to a new line in this way, which is one of the major reasons they were replaced for layouts with CSS layout approaches.

`<div>` or other HTML tags will automatically wrap if they don't fit within the available space. You might want to consider restructuring your layout using divs and styling with floats or better yet flexbox (and media queries) to readily support multiple device widths.

Here is a codepen which shows a simple example of a floated layout and changing style rules with media queries (based on window size): http://codepen.io/agentfitz/pen/WrBLJQ

Comment: Sure thing, added codepen example. Bootstrap is one way to do it (if you want to be able to do it without spending much time learning css), but wrestling with css frameworks is not always fun. Personally, I prefer a native, mobile-first solution (such as flexbox), but it all depends on your project and how much time you want to invest in your css skills.

Answer (score 0):

A good work-around would be to use the css display tables see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wvep5ga1/16/

You could then move them around just like any other div and not be constrained to the limits of the `<table>`.

HTML

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell mobile-row">
      here is your work around
    </div>
    <div class="cell mobile-row">
      here is your work around
    </div>
    <div class="cell mobile-row">
      here is your work around
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell mobile-row">
      here is your work around
    </div>
    <div class="cell mobile-row">
      here is your work around
    </div>
    <div class="cell mobile-row">
      here is your work around
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table {
  display: table
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .mobile-row {
    display: block;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
  }
}
```